# pyspark Window function range is going backwards?

Tags: pyspark

I am am using a Window function in pyspark to compute the future cumulative sum, but the range is working backwards from what I expect. If I specify all future rows, what I am getting is a cumulative sum over the past. Do I have a bug? Here is my example:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


def undiscountedCummulativeFutureReward(df):
    windowSpec = Window \
        .partitionBy('user') \
        .orderBy('time') \
        .rangeBetween(0, sys.maxsize)

    tot_reward = F.sum('reward').over(windowSpec)

    df_tot_reward = df.withColumn('undiscounted', tot_reward)
    return df_tot_reward


def makeData(spark):
    data = [{'user': 'bob', 'time': 3, 'reward': 10},
            {'user': 'bob', 'time': 4, 'reward': 9},
            {'user': 'bob', 'time': 5, 'reward': 11},
            {'user': 'jo', 'time': 4, 'reward': 6},
            {'user': 'jo', 'time': 5, 'reward': 7},
            ]
    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField('user', T.StringType(), False),
                           T.StructField('time', T.IntegerType(), False),
                           T.StructField('reward', T.IntegerType(), False)])

    return spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)


def main(spark):
    df = makeData(spark)
    df = undiscountedCummulativeFutureReward(df)
    df.orderBy('user', 'time').show()
    return df
```

When I run this, I get

```
+----+----+------+------------+                                                 
|user|time|reward|undiscounted|
+----+----+------+------------+
| bob|   3|    10|          30|
| bob|   4|     9|          20|
| bob|   5|    11|          11|
|  jo|   4|     6|          13|
|  jo|   5|     7|           7|
+----+----+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `rangeBetween` it says:

```
We recommend users use ``Window.unboundedPreceding``, ``Window.unboundedFollowing``,
and ``Window.currentRow`` to specify special boundary values, rather than using integral
values directly.
```

and that fixed it - if I change the window spec to

```
windowSpec = Window \
    .partitionBy('user') \
    .orderBy('time') \
    .rangeBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

then it works as expected.